# angular material grid list: repeat a set of grid-list-tiles

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, material-design, angular-material

I hava an angular material **grid list**. It consists of a single row (spanning 4 columns), and a number of 'item' rows, each consisting of 4 tiles. [This](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YGVpXX) codepen illustrates the problem.

Each item should have its own row, i.e. for each item, 4 tiles should be rendered.

To do this, I cannot put the `ng-repeat` on a tile, because this would repeat only a single tile. I tried wrapping the 4 tiles within a div that contains the `ng-repeat`, but this screws up the layout (in Codepen: uncomment the div).

[image]

This is my code:

```
<md-grid-list md-cols="4" md-row-height="4:1" md-gutter="8px">
    <md-grid-tile class="gray" md-colspan="4">
      <div layout="column" layout-fill>this is a static row</div>
    </md-grid-tile>
    <div ng-repeat="item in appCtrl.items">

      <md-grid-tile class="gray">
        <div layout="column" layout-fill>this row</div>
      </md-grid-tile>
      <md-grid-tile class="gray">
        <div layout="column" layout-fill>should repeat</div>
      </md-grid-tile>
      <md-grid-tile class="gray">
        <div layout="column" layout-fill>for every</div>
      </md-grid-tile>
      <md-grid-tile class="gray">
        <div layout="column" layout-fill>item</div>
      </md-grid-tile>
    </div>
</md-grid-list>
```

Any ideas on how to properly render a grid list with a repeating set of tiles?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `div` is breaking the layout. Use a `md-grid-tile` with `md-colspan` of 4, and break it using `div`s inside:

```
<md-grid-list md-cols="4" md-row-height="4:1" md-gutter="8px">
    <md-grid-tile class="gray" md-colspan="4">
        <div layout="column" layout-fill>this is a static row</div>
    </md-grid-tile>
    <md-grid-tile class="gray"  ng-repeat="item in appCtrl.items" md-colspan="4">
        <div layout="row" flex>
            <div flex>this row</div>
            <div flex>should repeat</div>
            <div flex>for every</div>
            <div flex>item</div>
        </div>
      </md-grid-tile>
</md-grid-list>
```

[Demo in codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RGVoBp)